# Having trouble w/ saving rgl image in R

Tags: r, rgl

I am creating a 3D plot with `plot3d` function as follows;

```
plot3d(x=c3$`R`, y=c3$`E`, z=c3$Penalty, type="p", col="red",
       xlab="x Axis", ylab="y Axis",
       zlab="Cost",
       size=7,radius=200, lwd=30, box=F)
```

It perfectly work and I obtain [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVuZN.jpg). Then, when I try to save the image with a high resolution, I am getting a super weird image as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUXPc.jpg).

The code that I am using to save the image is `rgl.postscript("myImage.pdf","pdf")`. I would appreciate if someone could let me know what I might be doing wrong.

Edit: If I run the code provided by @RoB below, I am getting a [wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvYpE.jpg) again. Also, `rgl.snapshot` works fine, but it creates a PNG file, which is really low quality.

Platform: Windows 10

R Version: 3.6.1

R Studio Version: 1.2.1335

rgl Version: 0.100.30

Comment: Since your problem is not directly linked to your code, could you provide some info about your platform ? (OS, R version, rgl pkg version, etc)

Comment: @RoB I updated my post and added those information.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following code works fine.

```
library(rgl)
dat <- data.frame(x = -50:50, y = -50:50, z = rnorm(101))

plot3d(x=dat$x, y=dat$y, z=dat$z,
       type="p", col="orange", 
       xlab="x Axis", ylab="y Axis", zlab="Cost",
       size=7, radius=200, lwd=30, box=F)

# fiddle with rotation/size, then
rgl.postscript("~/Desktop/test.pdf", fmt = "pdf")
```

[image]

Comment: Is this what you see when you open the PDF file?

Comment: @ball_jan Yes, that's it.

Comment: There is definitely something wrong and I don't know what that is. Here is what I get after running your code. https://imgur.com/ECWeqHP